# When does a character Who Leads get her Follower?

Tags: cypher-system, the-strange, followers-and-hirelings

If a PC picks up the Leads focus when translating to a new recursion, when does her Follower show up, and would the character recognize him as such?

Is the Follower an actual native of the recursion, or does he only exist while the character is present (and has the Leads focus)?

If she then translates to a different recursion or a prime world, then returns to the Follower's recurion, is that Follower waiting for her, does she have to seek him out, or does the Follower somehow "know" that she has returned, and seek her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it makes sense to have followers appear automatically. Have them *arise from the story*. If the character does not take any inspiring action, why should anybody follow them?

Once they take visible and inspiring action, it's easy to GM-rule that one of the attending NPCs is so smitten they tag along, but maybe it's an Intellect check against the level of the new follower -- does that patriotic speech really work? The character of the follower -- do-gooder, religious fanatic, or complete crackpot -- depends on the recruiting scene as well.

Of course, you can admit the player to "have picked up" a follower between sessions if they insist on the two-week rule from the Focus description, but would advise against that. Have them roleplay for it!

Regarding the specifics of The Strange.

> Is the Follower an actual native of the recursion, or does he only exist while the character is present (and has the Leads focus)?

The latter makes little to no sense. Use logic!

> is that Follower waiting for her, does she have to seek him out, or does the Follower somehow "know" that she has returned, and seek her?

Whatever makes sense. How deep is the relationship? Does the character have a home base in that recursion? Has the follower thrown away all other ties?

Maybe, one day, the follower gains enough Spark to even tag along across recursions!

ma_il raises an interesting point regarding Spark. The way I understand the setting, everybody who does *not* have the Spark is on autopilot within their recursion. There is no way such a "character" would attach themselves to a foreign individual that is not part of the "program". Hence, my ruling would be that followers have to have the Spark. If the recursion does not have any such individuals, too bad for the player.

Comment: Okay, that makes the most sense.  The "logic" behind having the Follower "disappear" when the character is not in the recursion stemmed from the abeyance of the character and her belongings when she translates out - I hadn't thought of the Follower as being an "actual" being, but merely an extension of the character's Focus - somewhat like teh clones of the Spawns focus.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't come across anything specifying that in the rules.

Having said that, it may depend on your style of play and maybe even on the recursion in which the character picks up the focus:

In a very young recursion, where there are very few inhabitants with the Spark, it is more likely that a follower happens to be in the vicinity of the character once he or she transitions in. The rules of the recursion guide that person to be at hand.

On the other hand, if everyone in the recursion has the Spark, I would find it much more appropriate if the follower would first need at least to gain knowledge of the characters presence in some way before acting on it and searching them out.

There is a multitude of ways to play out this particular focus. One variant may even be to let the character do interviews (in-game or off-screen) with a number of applicants before choosing someone. GM or player may use this to come up with some quirks to personalize the follower so that they aren't just lemmings dogging the PCs heels.

To sum it up: tailor it to your character, recursion and play style and be creative ;)